# JS mobile menu toggle affects children with submenus as well

Tags: javascript, html

I have this small script that is basically a toggler for a mobile menu. There are some parent links that contain multiple items, some of the child items also have sub menus. I have a small script that works, but it also affects the submenus of the children.

It's basically like this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="true">
    <li id="menu-item-69" class="first-submenu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-60 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-69">
        <a href="/" aria-current="page">ÜBER MEK</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu active">
            <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-293"><a href="/">KOOPERATIONEN</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="/">LINKS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1061" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1061"><a href="/">SCHULUNGEN</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-1056" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1056"><a href="/">EXTERNE SCHULUNGEN</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1057" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1057"><a href="/">INHOUSE SCHULUNGEN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1066" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1066"><a href="/">KARRIERE</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1075" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1075"><a href="/">BLOG</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)").matches) {
 document.querySelector('.menu')
      .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var li = event.target.closest("li")
        var submenu = li.querySelector("ul")
        if (submenu) {
          event.preventDefault()
          submenu.classList.toggle("active")
        }
      })
    }
```

Any idea on how I could adapt this little script so only the first menu items with submenus will be affected by it? (UBER MEK) for instance in the above example. Currently (KOOPERATIONEN) and (SCHULUNGEN) are affected as well.

Thanks!

Comment: using CSS properties like **position and z-index** may fix your problem

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: just refer this CSS http://jsfiddle.net/s2t19ekm/

Comment: It's built in wordpress, I can't change the syntax or add IDs, only classes

Comment: cant you append the CSS with jquery for eg, `document.getElementById('id').class = 'your-class'`. I havent worked with wordpress.